# Java SE specifications |S| symbol

Tags: java, specifications, subtyping

I'm reading the Java Specification for subtyping and casting I know S <: T means S is a subtype of T. However, I don't understand what does |S| <: |T| means? For example in this context:

> One type argument is a type variable or wildcard, with an upper bound
>   (from capture conversion, if necessary) of S; and the other type
>   argument T is not a type variable or wildcard; and neither |S| <: |T|
>   nor |T| <: |S|.

|T| is the type of T reference? Does it refer to the class of T?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation "|T|" means the type erasure of type "T", according to the definition of type erasure in the [JLS, Section 4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6).

> Type erasure is a mapping from types (possibly including parameterized types and type variables) to types (that are never parameterized types or type variables). We write |T| for the erasure of type T. The erasure mapping is defined as follows:
>
> - The erasure of a parameterized type (§4.5) G is |G|.
> - The erasure of a nested type T.C is |T|.C.
> - The erasure of an array type T[] is |T|[].
> - The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.
> - The erasure of every other type is the type itself.

So, "|S| <: |T|" means that the erasure of S is a subtype of the erasure of T.